# Correct preposition when saying "Carrots grow ..."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was writing something and realised I don't know where carrots grow. Do they grow *under the ground*, or *on the ground*, or *in the ground*? Or something else entirely?

Furthermore, someone told me I should use *land* instead of *ground*. Would that be the case?

In short, how do I correct the following sentence:

> The carrots grow **in** the **ground**.

Comment: Your sentence is just fine as it is. Carrots grow in the ground.

Comment: And "land" is definitely incorrect in that usage, though we might say "The grass grows well on that land."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"... in the ground" is correct.  "Under" would not be wrong either.  As an alternative, the word "underground" can be used as an adverb: "Carrots grow underground"